# Add connectionstring in ASP.NET5.0 with EF7 for using dll repository library(based on EF6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If it is EF7 DbContext, in asp.net 5.0 project configure as:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
.AddSqlServer()
.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

How about configure the connectionstring for EF6 DbContext used in repository library which I referenced?

BTW, in previous projects, only need to add connectionStrings element with connectionstring name used in EF6 DbContext in app.config or web.config. 
But set in web.config of asp.net 5.0 project, it does not work. It will use the default(I think it is proceeded by EF7) like below:

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=connectionStringName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

I can set the connectionstring in repository library config file, but this is not a good idea, right?

Comment: ++ Proviously, if any project needs to refer to this library, just need to add the connectionstring element in the config file of the project. But ASP.NET5.0 project is totally different. Can I add "connectionstring" in startup.cs that ASP.NET5.0 can read it and library can use it?

Comment: The library should have something like a context factory that takes a connection string as parameter. An xxx.config file is only one way of injecting an external dependency, but a library that is used in multiple projects shouldn't prescribe this highly specific method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Finally, I have to change DbContext constructor in the repository library and it works now. Thanks so much. Following https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have to change DbContext constructor in the repository library and it works now. Thanks so much. Following docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html